# Uniformly continuity of a real valued function $f$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-continuity

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function given by $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{g(x-k)}{2^k}$ 
>   where $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a uniformly continuous function such that the series converges for each $x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$.
>   Then show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

How I show this. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: `\infty` gives you $\infty$, and the command for fraction is `\frac`. As for the question itself, what have you tried?

Comment: Try and use Rabee's Theorem @abcdmath

Comment: I tried to show that the series is uniformly convergent. But if the series is uniformly convergent , then can I say f is uniformly continuous? @Arthur

Comment: I like  this exercise. it looks weird but follows just by using definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ then given $\epsilon>0$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$.
Hence, if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|(x-k)-(y-k)|=|x-y|<\delta$ and
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|g(x-k)-g(y-k)|}{2^k}\leq 
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}=\epsilon,$$
that is $f$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @abcdmath Any further doubt?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function given by $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{g(x-k)}{2^k}$ 
where $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a uniformly continuous function such that the series converges for each $x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\varepsilon >0$ since $g $ is uniformly continuous there is $\delta >0$ such that for every $x,y\in\mathbb R$ if $|x-y|<\delta$ then

$$ |g(x)-g(y)|< \varepsilon $$

Accordingly, if $ |y-x|<\delta$ then for every  $k\ge 0$ $|(x-k)-(y-k)|= |x-y|< \delta $ that is $$|g(x-k) -g(y-k)|<\varepsilon $$
Therefore
$$ |f(x) -f(y)|\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|g(x-k) -g(y-k)|}{2^k} < \varepsilon \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \varepsilon $$